# ArcGIS for Desktop is rotating attachment pictures from feature service of ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, image, data-driven-pages, attachments

I have a web map on my ArcGIS Online account.

In that map are features (line polygon points) with a picture attached to each feature.

After saving the feature service as a local copy on my desktop the attached images are rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise.  This is when displayed on the info tool or on data driven pages.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.1.

Comment: are the symbols being rotated by a field on ArcGIS Online? Might help if you include some screenshots of the issue

Answer (score 1):

The rotation of the image gets saved in the .mxd, but it doesn't actually rotate the source image. Need to un-attach, rotate, and then re-attach.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/158380

...but the 90deg roration is normal.
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/160610